# Como definir os tipos de dados das colunas de uma JTable igual a do banco de dados MySql?

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

Criei uma interface gráfica no Netbeans onde inseri uma JTable dentro de um FORM JFrame. Eu tenho um Banco de dados MySql cujas colunas são:

**Id**: Integer

**Nome**: String

**Ativo**: Boolean

Porém quando utilizo: **jTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel())** (método da biblioteca RS2XML.jar), a JTable é preenchida toda como String.

Como faço para que a JTable seja preenchida com os tipos de dados corretos igual ao banco de dados (Integer, String e Boolean)?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza o parse.
Por exemplo, você está com uma variável do tipo String mas no banco é int, você coloca:
int x = Integer.parseInt(variavel String);

assim você terá uma variável do mesmo tipo que o seu banco.

Comment: Não tem como fazer assim, porque o método resultsetToTableModel() já joga os valores direto na tabela.